# Culling spikes with WaitForJob

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have 9 terrains that were generated at runtime.

[image]

Each terrain's heightmap is 128*128. When I run on android device I encounter culling spikes like this:

[image]

What is this WaitForJob? There is nothing happening in the scene so why the spike?

Comment: I think this is how Unity3D Engine reservs resources of CPU and/or GPU. It is basicly free resources to be used when something happens.

Comment: That's not the case. It creates spikes and freezes gameplay so it is by no means intentional